# Working with Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability

Let $X$∼$\exp(1)$, compute $P(|X −10| ≥ 2)$ using Chebyshev.

My attempt:

The mean of $X = 1$ and the $Var(X)=1$. Thus,

$P(|X −10| ≥ 2) = 1 - P(|X −10| < 2) = 1 - P(7<X-1 < 11)$

But after that I can't return to the absolute value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chebyshev allows you to *bound* probabilities, not compute them. I don't think this is a good exercise for Chebychev, but if you want to apply it, here is one thing you can do:

$$P(|X-10| \ge 2) \ge P(X \le 8) = P(0 \le X  \le 8) = P(|X-1| \le 7)
\ge 1 - \frac{1}{7^2} \approx 1 - 0.0204.$$

However, if you want to compute this probability, you can do so directly:
$$P(|X-10| \ge 2)
= \int_0^8 e^{-x} \, dx + \int_{12}^\infty e^{-x} \, dx
= 1 - e^{-8} + e^{-12}
\approx  1 - 0.000329
\ge 1 - 0.0204.$$

Comment: How did you go from $P(0≤X≤8)$ to $P(|X−1|≤7)$? I subtract -1 in every side but I can't return to the absolute value.

Comment: @Mystery $|X-1| \le 7$ is equivalent to $-6 \le X \le 8$. But since $X$ is a nonnegative random variable, this is equivalent to $0 \le X \le 8$.